# Error in z[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions when doing bootstrapping samples

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am using a ratio of means to estimate the population, `T = mean(xbar)/ mean(u_bar)` using bootstrapping method and I'm getting this error

```
message, Error in z[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions.
```

```
pop = read_xlsx("US_pop.xlsx")
attach(pop)
z = cbind(X,U)

T = function(z) 
{
  T = (mean(z[,1]) / mean(z[,2]))         ## I am using a ratio of means to estimate the population = mean(xbar)/ mean(u_bar)
}

T_stat = T(z)

nBoot = 2e5                                          # number of bootstrapping sample
Tboot = matrix(0,nBoot,2)                          # est. T for each sample
set.seed(123)

for (i in 1:nBoot) 
{
    {
  Tboot[i] = T(sample(z,replace = TRUE))
}
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you, if you provided a minimal reproducible example, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Judging from the provided code, the dimensions of z are the problem. I can only recommend to not name functions "T" or "F" because those are used for TRUE and FALSE in R and it can lead to problems later on.

Comment: You create `Tboot` with 2 columns and then refer to `Tboot[i]`. Also, `T` is a symbol for `TRUE`. Though to use it doesn't throw an error, couldn't you use something else?

Answer (score 1):

The error of the code in the question is in

```
sample(z, replace = TRUE)
```

`z` is a matrix but when `sample` is applied to it `z` is seen as a vector and the return value is no longer of class `"matrix"` and `"array"`:

```
class(z)
#[1] "matrix" "array" 

class(sample(z, replace = TRUE))
#[1] "numeric"
```

Therefore, to subset `z[, 1]` **in the function** is not to subset the same `z` but the function argument of the same name. And this is what `sample` returned, a numeric vector.

Here is the function and its call, corrected. Tested with the data at the end.

```
STAT <- function(z) mean(z[, 1])/mean(z[, 2])

T_stat <- STAT(z)

nBoot <- 2e5
Tboot <- numeric(nBoot)
set.seed(123)
for (i in 1:nBoot) {
  j <- sample(nrow(z), replace = TRUE)
  Tboot[i] = STAT(z[j, ])
}

T_stat
#[1] 1.826662
mean(Tboot)
#[1] 1.878934
```

---

A simpler alternative is function `boot` in base package `boot`. The function is modified in order to have an index variable `i` as argument.

```
STAT2 <- function(z, i) mean(z[i, 1])/mean(z[i, 2])

set.seed(123)
b <- boot::boot(z, STAT2, R = nBoot)

b
#
#ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#
#
#Call:
#boot::boot(data = z, statistic = STAT2, R = nBoot)
#
#
#Bootstrap Statistics :
#    original     bias    std. error
#t1* 1.826662 0.05249037   0.4181259

mean(b$t)
#[1] 1.879153
```

**Test data creation code**

```
set.seed(2020)
X <- rexp(20, rate = 1/4)
U <- rexp(20, rate = 1/2)
z <- cbind(X, U)
```